# maven is install error

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I use windows7 64-bit
reference site : [enter link description here](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/38/build-install-configure-run-apache-hadoop-2.2.0-microsoft-windows-os)

This problem isn't solve

```
   [INFO] Final Memory: 44M/175M

    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.8.1:jar (module-javadocs) on project hadoop-common: ArchiverException: Error while creating archive: Problem creating jar: C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\target\hadoop-common-2.2.0\bin\hadoop.dll (Access is denied) -> [Help 1]

    [ERROR]

    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

    [ERROR]

    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

    [ERROR] [Help 1] [enter link description here][1]

    [ERROR]

    [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

    [ERROR] mvn <goals> -rf :hadoop-common
```

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem here... :-(

EDIT : It works !!

Chmod the cygdrive with

`chmod a+rw /cygdrive/c/hdfs/hadoop-2.2.0-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/hadoop-common-2.2.0/bin/*`

I've seen is this :

```
ls -al C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\target\hadoop-common-2.2.0\bin
drwxr-xr-x 1 AM341772 Domain Users      0 Mar 21 18:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 AM341772 Domain Users      0 Mar 21 17:05 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 AM341772 Domain Users   4993 Mar 21 17:05 hadoop
-rw-r--r-- 1 AM341772 Domain Users   7770 Mar 21 17:05 hadoop.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 AM341772 Domain Users  50176 Mar 21 17:04 hadoop.dll
-rw-r--r-- 1 AM341772 Domain Users   6881 Mar 21 17:04 hadoop.exp
-rw-r--r-- 1 AM341772 Domain Users  11878 Mar 21 17:04 hadoop.lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 AM341772 Domain Users 347136 Mar 21 17:04 hadoop.pdb
-rw-r--r-- 1 AM341772 Domain Users 204944 Mar 21 17:04 libwinutils.lib
-rwxr-xr-x 1 AM341772 Domain Users   1837 Mar 21 17:05 rcc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 AM341772 Domain Users  40448 Mar 21 17:04 winutils.exe
-rw-r--r-- 1 AM341772 Domain Users 371712 Mar 21 17:04 winutils.pdb

ls -al /cygdrive/c/hdfs/hadoop-2.2.0-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/hadoop-common-2.2.0/bin
total 1044
drwxrwxrwx+ 1 AM341772 Domain Users      0 Mar 21 18:19 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 AM341772 Domain Users      0 Mar 21 17:05 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 AM341772 Domain Users   4993 Mar 21 17:05 hadoop
-rwxrwxrwx  1 AM341772 Domain Users   7770 Mar 21 17:05 hadoop.cmd
----------  1 AM341772 Domain Users  50176 Mar 21 17:04 hadoop.dll
----------  1 AM341772 Domain Users   6881 Mar 21 17:04 hadoop.exp
----------  1 AM341772 Domain Users  11878 Mar 21 17:04 hadoop.lib
----------  1 AM341772 Domain Users 347136 Mar 21 17:04 hadoop.pdb
----------  1 AM341772 Domain Users 204944 Mar 21 17:04 libwinutils.lib
-rwxrwxrwx  1 AM341772 Domain Users   1837 Mar 21 17:05 rcc
----------  1 AM341772 Domain Users  40448 Mar 21 17:04 winutils.exe
----------  1 AM341772 Domain Users 371712 Mar 21 17:04 winutils.pdb
```

It's a cygwin problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a process running that has a lock on that file.

Make sure all Java processes (and anything else that may be using that file, e.g. Winzip, command prompt windows) are stopped and to be sure you could restart your machine

Comment: I perform restart machine still undergo problems

Comment: Still the *same* problems? Could you have a process starting on startup that uses the file? Maybe copy the project into a different dir and try with that to be sure

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, fixed by running chmod command from the Windows SDK command prompt:

```
chmod -R 777 <hadoop-common-folder>
```